# Using IOCP with UDP?

Tags: c++, performance, networking, udp, iocp

I'm pretty familiar with what ***Input/Output Completion Ports*** are for when it comes to **TCP**.

But what, if I am for example coding a FPS game, or anything where need for low latency can be a deal breaker - I want immediate response to the player to provide the best playing experience, even at cost of losing some spatial data on the go. It becomes obvious that I should use **UDP** and aside from sending coordinate updates frequently, I should also implement kind of semi-reliable protocol (afaik TCP induces packet loss in UDP so we should avoid mixing these two) to handle such events like chat messages, or gunshots where packet loss may be crucial.

Let's say I'm aiming at performance which would apply to MMOFPS game that allows to meet hundreds of players in one, persistent world, and aside from fighting with guns, it allows them to communicate through chat messages etc. - something like this actually exists and works well - check out PlanetSide 2.

Many articles there on the net (e.g. these from msdn) say overlapped sockets are the best and IOCP is god-tier concept, but they don't seem to distinguish the cases where we use other protocols than TCP.

So there is almost no reliable information about I/O techniques used when developing such a server, I've looked at [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/533159-article-using-udp-with-iocp/), but the topic seems to be highly controversial, and I've also seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1871/IP-Multicasting-Using-I-O-completion-ports-with-UD) , but considering discussions in the first link, I don't know if I should follow assumptions of the second one, **whether I should use IOCP with UDP at all**, and if not, **what is the most scalable and efficient I/O concept when it comes to UDP**.

Or maybe am I just making another premature optimization and no thinking ahead is required for the moment ?

Thought about posting it on gamedev.stackexchange.com, but this question better applies to general-purpose networking I think.

Comment: It might help if you provided a bit more background about what sort of communication you're intending to conduct?  And between whom?  How often?  etc.

Comment: For TCP: you have a connection handle for each client. For UDP: there is no connection, hence no handle. IOCP is useful if you have lots of handles, there for it is IMHO irrelevant for UDP. Instead, you may select on your UDP socket or you just call recvfrom, if errno = WouldBlock/TryAgain then there is nothing to receive...

Comment: @Malkacoglu what about cases where "reliable UDP" is needed ? Should I implement my own-rolled IOCP on the top of the simplest recvfroms/sendtos for my virtual UDP connections ?

Comment: IMHO, Making UDP reliable is a higher level mechanism, IOCP or similar  I/O notification function cannot guarantee reliability for UDP. IOCP cannot even guarantee anything for TCP. The reliability of TCP is a direct property of TCP, IOCP has no role in it...

Comment: @Malkocoglu 
you misunderstood me. I meant "if for UDP, IOCP is not okay and for TCP is okay, then, using only UDP in my application for both reliable and unreliable transports, should I implement my own-rolled IOCP mechanisms to make these reliable transports more efficient" ?

Comment: @Anonymous: Sorry, yes, you are right...

Comment: Consider Boost.Asio which uses IOCP under the hood.

Comment: A couple of things you might find interesting [Gaffer On Games](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/)(a set of networking articles by a pro game dev), and [enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) (a networking library for games, builds various features on top of UDP).

Comment: @stonemetal I already know Glenn's articles, but +1 for citing these interesting links. Though, my question is a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not recommend using this, but *technically* the most efficient way to receive UDP datagrams would be to just block in `recvfrom` (or `WSARecvFrom` if you will). Of course, you'll need a dedicated thread for that, or not much will happen otherwise while you block.

Other than with TCP, you do *not* have a connection built into the protocol, and you do not have a stream without defined borders. That means you get the sender's address with every datagram that comes in, and you get a whole message or nothing. Always. No exceptions.
Now, blocking on `recvfrom` means one context switch to the kernel, and one context switch back when something was received. It won't go any faster by having several overlapped reads in flight either, because only one datagram can arrive on the wire at the same time, which is by far the most limiting factor (CPU time is not the bottleneck!). Using an IOCP means at least 4 context switches, two for the receive and two for the notification. Alternatively, an overlapped receive with completion callback is not much better either, because you must `NtTestAlert` or `SleepEx` to run the APC queue, so again you have at least 2 extra context switches (though, it's only +2 for all notifications together, and you might incidentially already sleep anyway).

**However:**
Using an IOCP and overlapped reads is nevertheless the best way to do it, even if it is not the most efficient one. Completion ports are irrespective from using TCP, they work just fine with UDP, too. As long as you use an overlapped read, it does not matter what protocol you use (or even whether it's network or disk, or some other waitable or alertable kernel object).
It also does not really matter for either latency or CPU load whether you burn a few hundred cycles extra for the completion port. We're talking about "nano" versus "milli" here, a factor of one to one million. On the other hand, completion ports are *overall* a very comfortable, sound, and efficient system.

You can for example trivially implement logic for resending when you did not receive an ACK in time (which you *must* do when a form of reliability is desired, UDP does not do it for you), as well as keepalive.
For keepalive, add a waitable timer (maybe firing after 15 or 20 seconds) that you reset every time you receive *anything*. If your completion port ever tells you that this timer went off, you know the connection is dead.
For resends, you could e.g. set a timeout on `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, and every time you wake up find all packets that are more than so-and-so old and have not been ACKed yet.
The entire logic happens in one place, which is very nice. It's versatile, efficient, and hard to do wrong.

You can even have several threads (and, indeed, more threads than your CPU has cores) block on the completion port. Many threads sounds like an unwise design, but it is in fact the best thing to do.

A completion port wakes up to N threads in last-in-first-out order, N being the number of cores unless you tell it to do something different. If any of these threads block, *another one* is woken to handle outstanding events. This means that *in the worst case*, an extra thread may be running for a short time, but this is tolerable. In the average case, it keeps processor usage close to 100% as long as there is some work to do and zero otherwise, which is very nice. LIFO waking is favourable for processor caches and keeps switching thread contexts low.

This means you can block and wait for an incoming datagram and handle it (decrypt, decompress, perform logic, read someting from disk, whatever) and another thread will be immediately ready to handle the next datagram that might come in the next microsecond. You can use overlapped disk IO with the same completion port, too. If you have compute work (such as AI) to do that can be split into tasks, you can manually post (`PostQueuedCompletionStatus`) those on the completion port as well and you have a parallel task scheduler for free. All you have to do is wrap an `OVERLAPPED` into a structure that has some extra data after it, and use a key that you will recognize. No worrying about thread synchronization, it just magically works (you don't even *strictly* need to have an `OVERLAPPED` in your custom structure when posting your own notifications, it will work with any structure you pass, but I don't like lying to the operating system, you never know...).

It does not even matter much whether you block, for example when reading from disk. Sometimes this just happens and you can't help it. So what, one thread blocks, but your system still receives messages and reacts to it! The completion port automatically pulls another thread from its pool when it's necessary.

About TCP inducing packet loss on UDP, this is something that I am inclined to call an urban myth (although it is *somewhat correct*). The way this common mantra is worded is however misleading. It may have been true once upon a time (there exists research on that matter, which is, however, close to a decade old) that routers would drop UDP *in favour of* TCP, thereby inducing packet loss. That is, however, certainly not the case nowadays.
A more truthful point of view is that *anything* you send induces packet loss. TCP induces packet loss on TCP and UDP induces packet loss on TCP and vice versa, this is a normal condition (it's how TCP implements congestion control, by the way). A router will generally forward one incoming packet if the cable on the other plug is "silent", it will queue a few packets with a hard deadline (buffers are often *deliberately* small), optionally it may apply some form of QoS, and it will simply and silently *drop everything else*.
A lot of applications with rather harsh realtime requirements (VoIP, video streaming, you name it) nowadays use UDP, and while they cope well with a lost packet or two, they do not at all like significant, recurring packet loss. Still, they demonstrably work fine on networks that have a lot of TCP traffic. My phone (like the phones of millions of people) works exclusively over VoIP, data going over the same router as internet traffic. There is no way I can provoke a dropout with TCP, no matter how hard I try.
From that everyday observation, one can tell for certain that UDP is definitively not dropped in favour of TCP. If anything, QoS might favour UDP over TCP, but it most certainly doesn't penaltize it.
Otherwise, services like VoIP would stutter as soon as you open a website and be unavailable alltogether if you download something the size of a DVD ISO file.

**EDIT:**
To give somewhat of an idea of how simple life with IOCP can be (somewhat stripped down, utility functions missing):

```
for(;;)
{
    if(GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, &n, &k, (OVERLAPPED**)&o, 100) == 0)
    {
        if(o == 0) // ---> timeout, mark and sweep
        {
            CheckAndResendMarkedDgrams();  // resend those from last pass
            MarkUnackedDgrams();           // mark new ones
        } 
        else
        {   // zero return value but lpOverlapped is not null:
            // this means an error occurred
            HandleError(k, o);
        }
        continue;
    }

    if(n == 0 && k == 0 && o == 0)
    {
        // zero size and zero handle is my termination message
        // re-post, then break, so all threads on the IOCP will
        // one by one wake up and exit in a controlled manner
        PostQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    }
    else if(n == -1) // my magic value for "execute user task"
    {
        TaskStruct *t = (TaskStruct*)o;
        t->funcptr(t->arg);
    }
    else
    {
        /* received data or finished file I/O, do whatever you do */
    }
}
```

Note how the entire logic for both handling completion messages, user tasks, and thread control happens in one simple loop, no obscure stuff, no complicated paths, every thread only executes this same, identical loop.
The same code works for 1 thread serving 1 socket, or for 16 threads out of a pool of 50 serving 5,000 sockets, 10 overlapped file transfers, and executing parallel computations.

Comment: +1, especially for pointing out the fact that IOCP can handle network and application-specific events like logic simultaneously. As for TCP and packet loss, it's good to hear it is not a big problem anymore. So, do you suggest that I should have both protocols mixed in my server application, for example, UDP would be for time-sensitive spatial data, gunshots etc. (full reliability is not required) and TCP for things like chat messages and initial world data, where I would anyway try to reimplement my own TCP with UDP ? If so, is having only one CP good for so many purposes ?

Comment: And, wouldn't overhead of additionally having TCP connections on the other side outweigh the drawbacks of my own implemented reliability ? If not, it would be somewhat nice as TCP would do keepalives for me.

Comment: You can use several completion ports, but using just one is fine. I've been using a single completion port with hundreds of handles and posting thousands of user messages per second, and it works just fine. I'd not worry about overhead for having an extra socket, as long as no data is sent/received, the overhead is close to zero (a few kilobytes of buffer memory allocated, and zero CPU used). Using TCP for chat messages and loading level data at startup looks like a good idea, that's an usage pattern TCP is good at. About reliability etc. you must decide what exactly you need. If you ...

Comment: ... completely reimplement TCP on top of UDP, you would better use TCP in the first place (with Nagle disabled). On the other hand, if you don't need e.g. strict in-order delivery guarantee or can live with losing certain messages (such as position updates, if they are compensated with the next packet), then you can cut some big corners using UDP, of course. But this is something nobody else can answer, it depends on your design.

Comment: So, summarizing, if I anyway from time to time need reliable transport in my application, I should choose to mix TCP with UDP, and also use TCP to handle connection-specific issues for me - recognizing new connections and shutting down dead ones. No more keepalives handling, right ?

Comment: Yes, but... even with TCP you have to handle keepalive yourself, at least for a game. Although TCP does have such functionality, it is usually not enabled, and if it is enabled the default timeout is something like 2 hours -- so it's kind of useless for you. This works well for a web server, but you want to know about a lost connection as soon as possible, not after minutes or hours. Thus, you will always want to record when you've last sent and received something, and you will always want to regularly (maybe every 5 secs) send out a "probe" if you don't have anything else to send.

Comment: Thanks for your additional effort here. That's all I wanted to know about mixing TCP with UDP.

Comment: For a twitch game like an FPS, you never want to use TCP (even with nagle disabled). If a state packet gets dropped then the stream of state packets from the server halts until that one is resent, we'd rather just forget about the dropped one and take the next state packet. If you do have packets that need to be sent reliably, you still shouldn't use TCP because using TCP alongside UDP can induce packet loss in UDP.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen the code to many FPS games that use UDP as the networking protocol.

The standard solution is to send all the data you need to update a single game frame in  one large UDP packet. That packet should include a frame number, and a checksum. The packet should of course be compressed.

Generally the UDP packet contains the positions and velicities for every entity near the player, any chat messages that were sent, and all recent state changes. ( e.g. new entity created, entity destrouyed etc. )

Then the client listens for UDP packets. It will use only the packet with the highest frame number. So if out of order packets appear, the older packets are simply ignored.

Any packets with wrong checksums are also ignored.

Each packet should contain all the information to synchronize the client's game state with the server.

Chat messages get sent repeatedly over several packets, and each message has a unique message id For example, you retransmit the same chat message for say a full second worth of frames. If a client misses a chat message after getting it 60 times - then the quality of the network channel is just too low to play the game. Clients will display any messages they get in a UDP packet that have a message ID they have not yet displayed.

Similarly for objects being created or destroyed. All created or destroyed objects have a unique object Id set by the server. Objects get created or destroyed if the object id they correspond to has not been acted on before.

So the key here is to send data redundantly, and key all state transitions to unique id's set by the server.

@edit: Another poster mentioned that for chat messages you might want to use a different protocol on a different port. And they may be right about that probably being optimal. That is for message types where latency is not critical, but reliability is more important you might want to open up a different port and use TCP. But I'd leave that as a later excercise. It is certainly easier and cleaner at first for your game to use just one channel, and figure out the vagaries of multiple ports, multiple channels, with their various failure modes later. (e.g. what happens if the UDP channel is working, but the chat channel goes goes down? What if you succeed in opening one port and not the other? )

Answer (score 4):

When I did this [for a client](http://www.serverframework.com/clients/online-game-company.html) we used [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org/) as the base reliable UDP protocol and re-implemented this from scratch to use IOCP for the server side whilst using the freely available ENet code for the client side.

IOCP works fine with UDP and integrates nicely with any TCP connections that you might also be handling (we have TCP, WebSocket or UDP client connections in and TCP connections between server nodes and being able to plug all of these into the same thread pool if we want is handy).

If absolute latency and UDP packet processing speed is most important (and it's unlikely it *really* is) then a using the new Server 2012 RIO API might be worth it, but I'm not convinced yet (see [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/03/windows-8-registered-io-performance.html) for some preliminary performance tests and some example servers).

You probably want to look at using GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx() for dealing with your inbound data as it reduces the context switches per datagram as you can pull multiple datagrams back with a single call.

Comment: +1 for interesting annotation about GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx.

Answer (score 4):

A couple things:

**1)** As a general rule if you need reliability, you are best off just using TCP.  A competitive and perhaps even superior solution on top of UDP is possible, but it is extremely difficult to get right and have it perform properly. The main thing people implementing reliability on top of UDP don't bother with is proper flow control. You must have flow control if you intend to send large amounts of data and want it to gracefully take advantage of the bandwidth that is available at the moment (which changes continuously with route conditions). In practice, implementing anything other than essentially the same algorithm TCP uses is likely to be unfriendly to other protocols on the network as well. It's unlikely you will do a better job at implementing that algorithm than TCP does.

**2)** As for running TCP and UDP in parallel, it is not as huge of a concern these days as others have noted. At one time I heard that overloaded routers along the way were bias dropping UDP packets before TCP packets, which makes sense in some ways, since a dropped TCP packet will just be resent anyways, and a lost UDP packet often isn't. That said, I am skeptical that this actually happens. In particular, dropping a TCP packet will cause the sender to throttle back, so it may make more sense to drop the TCP packet.

The one case where TCP may interfere with UDP is that TCP by nature of it's algorithm is continuously trying to go faster and faster, unless it reaches a point where it loses packets, then it throttles back and repeats the process. As the TCP connection continuously bumps against that bandwidth ceiling, it is just as likely to cause UDP loss as TCP loss, which in theory would appear as if the TCP traffic was sporadically causing UDP loss.

However, this is a problem you will run into even if you put your own reliable mechanism on top of UDP (assuming you do flow control properly). If you wanted to avoid this condition, you could intentionally throttle the reliable data at the application layer. Typically in a game the reliable data rate is limited to the rate at which the client or server actually needs to send reliable data, which is often well below the bandwidth capabilities of the pipe, and thus the interference never occurs, regardless of whether it is TCP or UDP-reliable based.

Where things get a bit more difficult is if you are making a streaming asset game. For a game like FreeRealms which does this, the assets are downloaded from a CDN via HTTP/TCP and it will attempt to use all available bandwidth, which will increase packetloss on the main game channel (which is typically UDP). I have generally found the interference low enough that I don't think you should be worrying about it too much.

**3)** As for IOCP, my experience with them is very limited, but having done extensive game networking in the past, I am skeptical that they add value in the case of UDP. Typically the server will have a single UDP socket that is handling all incoming data. With hundreds of users connected, the rate at which the data is coming into the server is very high. Having a background thread doing a blocking call on the socket as others have suggested and then quickly moving the data into a queue for the main application thread to pick up is a reasonable solution, but somewhat unnecessary, since in practice the data is coming in so fast when under load that there is not much point in ever sleeping the thread when it blocks.

Let me put this another way, if the blocking socket call polled a single packet and then put the thread to sleep until the next packet came in, it would be context-switching to that thread thousands of times per second when the data rate got high. Either that, or by the time the unblocked thread executed and cleared the data, there would already be additional data ready to be processed as well. Instead, I prefer to put the socket in non-blocking mode and then have a background thread spin at around 100fps processing it (sleeping between polls as needed to achieve the frame rate). In this manner, the socket buffer will build up incoming packets for 10ms and then the background thread will wake up once and process all that data in bulk, then go back to sleep, thus preventing gratuitous context switches. I then have that same background thread do other send-related processing when it wakes up as well. Being entirely event-driven loses many of it's benefits when the data volume gets the least bit high.

In the case of TCP, the story is quite different, since you need an efficient mechanism to figure out which of hundreds of connects the incoming data is coming from and polling them all is very slow, even on a periodic basis.

So, in the case of UDP with a home-grown UDP-reliable mechanism on top of it, I typically have a background thread playing the same role that the OS plays... whereas the OS gets the data from the network card then distributes it to various logical TCP connections internally for processing, my background thread gets the data from the solitary UDP socket (via periodic polling) and distributes it to my own internal logical connection objects for processing. Those internal logical connections then put the application-level packet data into a thread-safe master-queue flagged with the logical connection they came from. The main application thread then processes that master-queue in, routing the packets directly to the game-level objects associated with that connection. From the main application threads point of view, it simply has an event driven queue it is processing.

The bottom line is that given that the poll call to the solitary UDP socket rarely comes up empty, it is difficult to imagine there is going to be a more efficient way to solve this problem. The only thing you lose with this method is you wait up to 10ms to wake up when in theory you could be waking up the instant the data first arrived, but that is only meaningful if you were under extremely light load anyways. Plus, the main application thread isn't going to be making use of the data until it's next frame cycle anyways, so the difference is moot, and I think the overall system performance is enhanced by this technique.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't hold a game as old as PlanetSide up as a paragon of modern network implementation.  Especially not having seen the insides of their networking library.  :)

Different types of communication require different methodologies.  One of the answers above talks around the differences between frame/position updates and chat messages, without recognizing that using the same transport for both is probably silly.  You should most definitely use a connected TCP socket between your chat implementation and the chat server, for text-style chat.  Don't argue, just do it.

So, for your game client doing updates via arriving UDP packets, the most efficient path from the network adapter through the kernel and into your application is (most likely) going to be a blocking recv.  Create a thread that rips packets off the network, verifies their validity (chksum match, sequence number increasing, whatever other checks you have), de-serializes the data into an internal object, then queue the object on an internal queue to the application thread that handles those sorts of updates.

But don't take my word for it: test it!  Write a small program that can receive and deserialize 3 or 4 kinds of packets, using a blocking thread and a queue to deliver the objects, then re-write it using a single thread and IOCPs, with the deserialization and queueing in the completion routine.  Pound enough packets through it to get the run time up in the minute range, and test which one is fastest.  Make sure something (i.e. some thread) in your test app is consuming the objects off the queue so you get a full picture of the relative performance.

Post back here when you have the two test programs done, and let us know which worked out best, mm'kay?  Which was fastest, which would you rather maintain in the future, which took the longest to get it working, etc.

Comment: Can't provide any more details, but "no."

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support many simultaneous connections, you need to use an event-driven networking approach. I know of two good libraries: [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) (used by [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)) and [libevent](http://libevent.org/). They are very portable and easy to use. I have successfully used libevent in an application supporting hundreds of parallel TCP/UDP(DNS) connections.

I believe using event-driven network i/o is not premature optimization in a server - it should be the default design pattern. If you want to do a quick prototype implementation it may be better to start in a higher level language. For JavaScript there is [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) and for Python there is [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). Both I can personally recommend.

Comment: Event-driven I/O is definitely a great tool.  Polling in Linux or kqueue in Mac OS or FreeBSD makes it pretty simple to do lots of reactive I/O very straightforward.  When Jonathan Lemon first implemented kqueue in FreeBSD, one of the demo programs for it was a simple chat server that would accept input from a TCP socket and blat it out on all the other connected TCP sockets, a super-simple chat server.  It could support and service 40,000 connected clients on a 450 MHz K6-2 machine.

Answer (score 0):

How about [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)
It supports [UDP](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html) and it is highly scalable.